# Android activity doesn't return from toolbar to main activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having an activity with a toolbar and when I press to go back to main activity the whole application is closing.

I put the parent page in the AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<activity
        android:name=".FindFriendsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
```

And in the java activity file in onCreate method :

```
  FindFriendsToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.find_friends_toolbar);
  FindFriendsToolbar.setBackgroundColor(Constant.color);
  setSupportActionBar(FindFriendsToolbar);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
  getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Find Friends");
```

I don't understand where I am wrong because I did the same thing in some others activities and it works.

Comment: What error message do you get in the console?

Comment: How are these activities declared in the manifest? How are you launching FindFriendsActivity? Are you saying that you are in MainActivity, press a button, go to FindFriendsActivity, and then press back on the toolbar doesn't go to MainActivity? You left pieces of the puzzle out, unfortunately. :/

Comment: For launching the Find friends activity I am having in the main activity a menu to go in the find friends activity and when I press back on toolbar my application close. An it seems like is no error in the LogCat.

Comment: @IoanaB can you post the code that is executed when the user taps the menu? Also, have you overridden any `onBackPressed()` methods in your second activity? Lastly, can you post your entire manifest? (or at least, the relevant parts, make sure no sensitive information is displayed if your project is under NDA or not OpenSource)

Comment: Can you share the code how you start this second activity? I wonder if you use any intent flag.

Comment: I found where I was wrong, when I was sending from main activity to find friends acitvity I was calling the finish() method. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Inside  `onCreate` method write this

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Outside  `onCreate` method write this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

make sure your theme has actionbar implemented